# Update table from Servlet (java) to MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, prepared-statement

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    connection.connect.connection();
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    Integer rating;
    String feedback, sql;
    PreparedStatement insert;
    RequestDispatcher reqdisp;
    try {
        connection.connect.con.setAutoCommit(false);

        rating = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("rating"));
        feedback = request.getParameter("feedback").trim();

        sql = "update Message set rating=?, feedback=? WHERE mid=LAST_INSERT_ID()";
        insert = connection.connect.con.prepareStatement(sql);
        insert.setObject(1, rating);
        insert.setObject(2, feedback);
        insert.executeUpdate();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Successfully inserted");
        connection.connect.con.commit();
        connection.connect.con.close();                                          
} catch (Exception e) {
   System.out.println(e);
        if (connection.connect.con != null) {
            try {
                connection.connect.con.rollback();
                connection.connect.con.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error");
            }
        }
    }
    reqdisp = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/thankYou.jsp");
    reqdisp.forward(request, response);

}
```

This code doesn't produce any error but the table never gets updated. Could someone help me find out the problem in my MySQL query? Thank you!

```
    Jun 20, 2017 12:29:09 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Messages' did not find a matching property.
Jun 20, 2017 12:29:09 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:TestingJSP' did not find a matching property.
Jun 20, 2017 12:29:09 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:JQueryAjaxDemo' did not find a matching property.
Jun 20, 2017 12:29:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M21
Jun 20, 2017 12:29:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          May 4 2017 22:42:36 UTC
Jun 20, 2017 12:29:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         9.0.0.0
Jun 20, 2017 12:29:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Mac OS X
Jun 20, 2017 12:29:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            10.12.5
Jun 20, 2017 12:29:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          x86_64
Jun 20, 2017 12:29:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Jun 20, 2017 12:29:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_131-b11
Jun 20, 2017 12:29:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Jun 20, 2017 12:29:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         /Users/rosemary/Documents/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0
Jun 20, 2017 12:29:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         /opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M21
Jun 20, 2017 12:29:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/Users/rosemary/Documents/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0
Jun 20, 2017 12:29:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M21
Jun 20, 2017 12:29:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=/Users/rosemary/Documents/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps
Jun 20, 2017 12:29:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M21/endorsed
Jun 20, 2017 12:29:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
Jun 20, 2017 12:29:09 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/Users/rosemary/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.]
Jun 20, 2017 12:29:10 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Jun 20, 2017 12:29:10 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Jun 20, 2017 12:29:10 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Jun 20, 2017 12:29:10 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Jun 20, 2017 12:29:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1553 ms
Jun 20, 2017 12:29:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Catalina]
Jun 20, 2017 12:29:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M21
Jun 20, 2017 12:29:11 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Jun 20, 2017 12:29:11 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Jun 20, 2017 12:29:11 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Jun 20, 2017 12:29:11 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Jun 20, 2017 12:29:11 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Jun 20, 2017 12:29:11 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Jun 20, 2017 12:29:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1488 ms
Tue Jun 20 12:29:18 BST 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Tue Jun 20 12:29:26 BST 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
```

There aren't any exceptions being printed out here. It results in a time out. MySQL values for rating is int and feedback is varchar.

Comment: How you catch-block Looks like?

Comment: Why you are updating always the last inserted record? if you have more than one user you never knows wich record will be updated

Comment: This is a small internal project, so for the time being only one user would be using at a time.

Comment: Do you see the message `Successfully inserted`? You never print out the exception if you get one. use a logging Framework and log out a message if you get an exeption

Comment: I don't get the successfully inserted message.

Comment: Then you get an exception that will not Shown because your code catch the exception and do not Show it in any way

Comment: Thanks! I will check that.

Comment: I added to print out the exception but nothing shows up. After a while I get "http://localhost:8080/Messages/MessageRating. Page load failed with error: The request timed out."

Comment: Please add the complete stacktrace to your question using the edit function

Comment: I have added it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LAST_INSERT_ID() was returning 0 for some reason so the SQL query never worked, that's the reason it never went into an exception.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use JOptionPane to give feedback to users.  JOptionPane (Swing framework) is for standalone clients.  You are writing a servlet so the client is a browser.  You should use response.getWriter() to get a writer and then use writer.println("<html>"); ...writer.println("<<html>"); to do your output.

Perhaps JOptionPane caused an error (check your server log) so the SQL update statement is not committed.  So no effect in database.